# Get a variable in a php file from a function in another file

Tags: php, sql, prestashop

I have a php file in the root and I would like to retrieve a variable that is in a function on another php file. I need it to make a SQL query

My php file in the root

```
<?php
    require dirname(__FILE__) . '/config/config.inc.php';
    require 'modules/pricefrom/pricefrom.php';

    $lowestPrice = Db::getInstance()->getValue('
            SELECT MIN(`price`)
            FROM `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'product_attribute`
            WHERE `id_product` = ' . (int)$id_product
    );
```

I need the $id_product from another file who is required and who is in a function and use a parameters of this function

```
 <?php
    ...
    public function hookDisplayPriceBlock($param) {
            $id_product = $param['id_product'];
            $id_product_attribute = $param['id_product_attribute'];
            $product = new Product();
            ...
```

I know there is an easy way to make it but I'm searching for hours and I can't find, can you help me guys ?

Answer (score 2):

In root use

```
require_once('<path to file2.php>');
$id_product = hookDisplayPriceBlock(<params>);
.....
```

File2

```
public function hookDisplayPriceBlock($param) {
    ...
    return $id_product;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, but I already have a "return" in my function, I can't put another one ! EDIT : ok, I can put an array and make multiples return sorry !

Comment: no problem, good luck with your code :)
other method is to copy and rename this function and edit it only for your case
, just in case that function it's used by other function

Comment: It certainly work but my function isn't declare in my root files, but the require is good, the error message says Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function hookDisplayPriceBlock()

Comment: I don't think the require it's ok

use 
`$file_pointer = "modules/pricefrom/pricefrom.php"; //Thinking this is the file

if (file_exists($file_pointer)) 
{
    echo "The file $file_pointer exists";
}`

to check if file exist with your path

Comment: @GuillaumeKS - You haven't shown much of the code, so a reply is not going to be exact.  The procedure is to tick this answer, if it solved your problem.